# Parsing 何を考えているかすぐ解るような態度は改めたほうがいい

Tags: grammar, words

> 「志貴さま。今のは姉さんにはその...」
>
> 黙っていてくださいとごにゃごにゃ呟く翡翠。
>
> 「なに、今のって琥珀さんに話しちゃいけないことなんだ。そっか。わかった」
>
> そんなことは、ぜひ琥珀さんに教えてあげなくては。
>
> 「……志貴さま。その、**なにを考えているかすぐ解るような態度は改めたほうがよろしいかと思います**」
>
> 「ん？なに、別になにも考えてないけど、俺」

[Shiki-sama, that thing I said just now...]

"Please do not tell it" Hisui mumbled.

[What, that thing now you mean it's something I should not tell Kohaku. I see. I understand]

That thing, I have to tell kohaku about it.

[Shiki-sama. Ehm, what you are thinking I immediately understand, an attitude like that I think you should change it]

[What? I am not thinking anything though]

---

I am not sure about

> 「……志貴さま。その、なにを考えているかすぐ解るような態度は改めたほうがよろしいかと思います」

Is my translation correct?

The fan-translation is:

> Shiki-sama. I think you should try not to show what you are thinking.

I am really not sure which one is correct, they are completely different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to parse this is 《なにを考えてるかすぐ解るような態度》は改めたほうが….

The thing that he should 改める is the 態度 whereby なにを考えてるかすぐ解る. That is, he should do something about that demeanor of his where anyone would immediately know what he is thinking. The grammatical content of the fan-translation is essentially correct here.

Your translation has all the right components, but it puts them together in a sort of incoherent way. In particular, Hisui is not directly saying that she knows what Shiki is thinking (though it's implied, obviously).

---

Addendum: I can't quite tell from your translation where you're getting tripped up on translating this, so maybe this breakdown will help.

- なにを考えているか = "what [Shiki] is thinking"
- なにを考えているかすぐ解る = "for [someone] to immediately know what [Shiki] is thinking"
- なにを考えているかすぐ解るような態度 = "an attitude/demeanor whereby [someone] immediately knows what [Shiki] is thinking" (let us call this entity "X")
- Xを改める = "to alter X"
- Xを改めたほうがよろしい = "it is better to alter X"
- Xを改めたほうがよろしいかと思います = "I think you ought to alter X"

Comment: My understaing is that shiki is not showing what he is yhinkinh with his attitude but that he has an attitude with which he acts as if he knows what others are thinking.
I do not understand why is it wrong.

Comment: ^ I think senshin's interpretation is perfect; the agent of 考えてる is Shiki and the agent of 解る is Hisui / other people, as in your translation "what you are thinking i immediately understand". Think of なにを考えているかすぐ解るような態度 as the relative clause of 態度で何を考えているかすぐ分かる (from your attitude I/we can immediately see what you're thinking)

Comment: Could you tell me if I am right?
わかる is intransitive and it means something like "be understood".
人を殺す理由 The reason whereby/why i kill people
人を殺す庭 The garden where i kill people
人を殺す殺人鬼 The killer who kills people
人殺しである人 The person who is a killer
What i missed was the way the subordinate is connected to the noun it modifies. 

So every relative can be  transformed with the appropriate particle

（ぼくは）理由で人を殺す　The reason whereby/why i kill people
（ぼくは）庭 に人を殺す The garden where i kill people
殺人鬼は人を殺す The killer who kills people
人は人殺しです The person who is a killer

Is my idea correct?

Comment: @senshin

なにを考えているかすぐ解る = "for [someone] to immediately know what [Shiki] is thinking" (I do not understand why you use: for [someone] to...)

Comment: @Splikie I'm just indicating _who_ immediately knows. This is not explicit in the text, since Japanese frequently drops subjects, but from context, the best interpretation I have is that the subject here is some arbitrary person (Hisui or someone else) who, upon witnessing Shiki's behavior, would know such-and-such.

Comment: [（僕に）志貴はなにを考えているか　すぐ解る]>態度

[(To me) what shiki is thinking is immediately understandable]>behaviour

The behaviour by which what shiki is thinking is understandable to me

[[（僕に）志貴はなにを考えているか　すぐ解る]>態度]]は改めたほうがよろしいかと思います 
As for the behaviour by which what shiki is thinking is understandable to me, how about changing it?
I think that what messed with my undestanding was the relative.

By reading @choco I understand that the 態度 is the means.
In every relative the name at the end which is modified by the rest could just become part of the sentence. 
態度で何を考えているかすぐ分かる
Somehow this feels easier.